# How to communicate with two keysight instruments by GPIB

Tags: python, gpib, pyvisa

I now have two keyight devices, one computer. I need to communicate with them through GPIB at the same time, but it seems to have encountered difficulties.
I can only get one address, I expect to get two addresses

```
import visa
rm=visa.ResourceManager()
rm.list_resources()
(u'GPIB0::22::INSTR',)
```

Comment: Did you check with keysight IO application whether you are detecting both?

Comment: @Hari,sorry, I don't know how to check it.Can you help me,thanks.

Comment: Do you have keysight IO library installed in your computer? If not, you need to install that. It is a GUI software which enables you to send commands and read output from connected instruments. https://www.keysight.com/main/software.jspx?id=2175637&pageMode=CV&cc=SG&lc=eng

Comment: The keysight IO library will help you to manually verify all the instruments are connected to the host pc

Comment: @Hari，my host Os is Ubuntu

Comment: @Hari,I got an IO error when i install IO Library

Answer (score 0):

[image]

@Hari, I got an IO error when i install IO library